# What exactly is causing my node class with a vector housing the pointers of the class to cause segmentation faults?

Tags: c++, tree, segmentation-fault, nodes, object-oriented-analysis

Currently I'm just starting off with creating nodes for my tree. The idea I had in mind was to simply create something like this:

```
class Node
{ 
private:
   int key_;
   std::vector< Node * > child_;
public:
   Node(int key)
      : key_(key), child_()
   {
   }
   Node * get_child(int key) const
   {
       return child_[key];
   }
};
```

Nothing too fancy, right?

Inside the main, I call all the header files and have initialized the whole entire thing like this

```
Node child(0);
```

What causes some frustration right now is when I try to simply just check if everything in my node is truly initialized. All I'm doing in the main is this.

```
std::cout << node.get_child(0) << std::endl;
```

The dreaded segmentation fault error comes up which means that the memory allocation of the vector is off. My question is this, if this is actually what's happening, what in my code is wrong so far? If it is not, please clarify on what exactly in my class template is wrong.

Comment: "The dreaded segmentation fault" - I wouldn't call it that. Reproducible crash bugs are usually the easiest class of bugs to debug.

Comment: Use `child_.at(key)` instead of `child_[key]`.

Comment: `which means that the memory allocation of the vector is off`, no the point where the segmentation fault happens does not need to be the point that is causing the segmentation fault. Any earlier action that resulted in undefined behavior can result in a segmentation fault at any point from that. `node.get_child(0)` could cause a segmentation fault if `child_` is empty, because then `child_[key]` is an out of bounds access. But as I said, the reason for the segfault could also already have happened earlier in your application. Without a [mcve] it is not possible to tell.

Comment: Does a Node logically own its children? If so, why does it just store raw pointers to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor for `Node`, you set the internal key value, and construct an *empty* vector.  You don't have any code shown that adds anything to the vector, and trying to access element 0 of an empty vector results in Undefined Behavior (a crash, in your case).

You probably want something like `child(1)` (to create one node in the vector), `child(key + 1, nullptr)` (to create null node pointers so that elements in the 0..k inclusive range are valid) or a loop in the constructor to set actual nodes into the vector.